# Android ServerSocket accept permission denied

Tags: java, android, serversocket

I was writing a sample android app which will create a simple http server, but faced a little problem.

Here's my MainActivity

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private ServerSocket ss;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Init();
    }

    private void Init() {
        Button btnStart = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_start);

        btnStart.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                new Thread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        try{
                            if(ss != null){
                                return;
                            }

                            ss = new ServerSocket(8080);

                            while (true) {
                                Socket s = ss.accept();
                                System.err.println("Client accepted");
                                new Thread(new SocketProcessor(s)).start();
                            }
                        } catch (Throwable throwable) {
                            throwable.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                }).start();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

And here's the SocketProcessor class

```
public class SocketProcessor implements Runnable {

    private Socket s;
    private InputStream is;
    private OutputStream os;

    public SocketProcessor(Socket s) throws Throwable {
        this.s = s;
        this.is = s.getInputStream();
        this.os = s.getOutputStream();
    }

    public void run() {
        try {
            readInputHeaders();
            writeResponse("<html><body><h1>Hello world!</h1></body></html>");
        } catch (Throwable t) {
                /*do nothing*/
        } finally {
            try {
                s.close();
            } catch (Throwable t) {
                    /*do nothing*/
            }
        }
        System.err.println("Client processing finished");
    }

    private void writeResponse(String s) throws Throwable {
        String response = "HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\n" +
                "Server: YarServer/2009-09-09\r\n" +
                "Content-Type: text/html\r\n" +
                "Content-Length: " + s.length() + "\r\n" +
                "Connection: close\r\n\r\n";
        String result = response + s;
        os.write(result.getBytes());
        os.flush();
    }

    private void readInputHeaders() throws Throwable {
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
        while (true) {
            String s = br.readLine();
            if (s == null || s.trim().length() == 0) {
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is it's giving me an exception saying that permission denied, although I do have the permission in my Manifest

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.mainserver.myapplication">

    <uses-permission android:name="ANDROID.PERMISSION.INTERNET" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>


</manifest>
```

What's wrong with the permission, am I missing something?

Thanks in advance.

Here is the stacktrace of my exception

```
09-17 17:01:11.072  12667-12842/com.mainserver.myapplication W/System.err﹕ java.net.SocketException: socket failed: EACCES (Permission denied)
09-17 17:01:11.072  12667-12842/com.mainserver.myapplication W/System.err﹕ at libcore.io.IoBridge.socket(IoBridge.java:660)
09-17 17:01:11.072  12667-12842/com.mainserver.myapplication W/System.err﹕ at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.create(PlainSocketImpl.java:198)
09-17 17:01:11.072  12667-12842/com.mainserver.myapplication W/System.err﹕ at java.net.PlainServerSocketImpl.create(PlainServerSocketImpl.java:38)
09-17 17:01:11.072  12667-12842/com.mainserver.myapplication W/System.err﹕ at java.net.ServerSocket.<init>(ServerSocket.java:103)
09-17 17:01:11.072  12667-12842/com.mainserver.myapplication W/System.err﹕ at java.net.ServerSocket.<init>(ServerSocket.java:74)
09-17 17:01:11.072  12667-12842/com.mainserver.myapplication W/System.err﹕ at com.mainserver.myapplication.MainActivity$1$1.run(MainActivity.java:37)
09-17 17:01:11.072  12667-12842/com.mainserver.myapplication W/System.err﹕ at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
09-17 17:01:11.072  12667-12842/com.mainserver.myapplication W/System.err﹕ Caused by: android.system.ErrnoException: socket failed: EACCES (Permission denied)
09-17 17:01:11.072  12667-12842/com.mainserver.myapplication W/System.err﹕ at libcore.io.Posix.socket(Native Method)
09-17 17:01:11.072  12667-12842/com.mainserver.myapplication W/System.err﹕ at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.socket(BlockGuardOs.java:282)
09-17 17:01:11.072  12667-12842/com.mainserver.myapplication W/System.err﹕ at libcore.io.IoBridge.socket(IoBridge.java:645)
09-17 17:01:11.072  12667-12842/com.mainserver.myapplication W/System.err﹕ ... 6 more
```

Comment: Hard to believe it's thrown by `accept().` Post the stack trace. Edit it into your question.

Comment: I guess you are calling `accept` on the main thread. Just extending Thread doesn't make the body of start() execute on a different thread. You should implement Runnable instead and feed it to a Thread instance to avoid this confusion.

Comment: Just saw, not only are you calling accept on the main thread, but also you are completely blocking it in an endless loop because of the while(true) in start() called in the click listener, which would end in an "Unresponsive App" anyway.

Comment: @Fildor why should I get an Unresponsive App if i'm running while loop in a thread, and also ss.accept() blocks the code so I'm not actually running the cycle infinitely?

Comment: You are not running it in a Thread. You are running it on the main thread.

Comment: @Fildor I changed it to the way you said, now my code is a little bit different but still no result. I'll edit my question to the newer version now, so you can look up.

Comment: Can you update the error message log?

Comment: Can you replace the permission by `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>`

Comment: @Skynet yeah it solved the problem. Thank you very much, i wouldn't figure it out!)

Comment: @Skynet write it as an answer, so it will be easier for other users to find out the solution)

Comment: Done, if that helps you can mark it as accepted :)

Comment: Naah, totally missed that. But my suggestions are still valid. You can try it out ...

Comment: @Fildor yeah I changed the way it was getting called anyway)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The permission you have declared needs to be replaced by:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
```

Answer (score -1):

I think you should create a new class, for the socket as now the only way to close is to close the app itself and maybe it should be ran in a async task.

Comment: This is not an answer to the question. These things should go to comments.